# VBA - How the colon `:` works in VBA code with condition

Tags: vba, excel

The colon operator `:` is a statement delimiter in VBA.

However, does anyone has a clue why the first three examples work and the fourth (when uncommented) produces an error?

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    If 1 = 1 Then: Debug.Print 1

    If 2 = 2 Then Debug.Print 2

    If 3 = 3 Then:
        Debug.Print 3

'   Gives error:
'    If 4 = 4 Then
'        Debug.Print 4

'Other Examples, from the comments and the answers:

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::         '<-- This seems to be ok

    If 5 = 5 Then Debug.Print "5a"::: Debug.Print "5b"
    If 6 = 0 Then Debug.Print "6a"::: Debug.Print "6b"

    If 7 = 0 Then:
        Debug.Print 7 ' Does not have anything to do with the condition...

    If 8 = 0 Then Debug.Print "8a"::: Debug.Print "8b" Else Debug.Print "8c"

End Sub
```

Comment: You have no "End If" after the last line. Else put ":" after "Then" on your last code If 4 = 4 Then:

Comment: @pokemon_Man, yeah, but number 3 works pretty good without any `End If`

Comment: number 3 has a colon and number 4 do not. Put a colon after "Then" on number 4

Comment: Then it should be exactly like number 3. And I want to write it on 2 lines.

Comment: then you'll need to add an End If

Comment: In my humble knowledge, `:` is used to put multiple commands on the same line as the VBA compiler will be a bit more performant having less lines to read. So it don't see the point of 3 and 4... Then you could use `_` to change line, but it's the same issue...

Comment: The `:` straight after the `Then` is basically ignored, other to force it into being a single line `If`.  `Debug.Print 3` is executed whether the previous statement is `If 3 = 3 Then` or `If 3 = 15 Then`.

Comment: When `python` programmer does `vba` you get the last (commented) statement

Comment: @ja72 - I knew it reminds me something :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the confusion comes from `3`. We'd think that `3` and `4` should behave the same. In fact, `3` is equivalent to this:

```
If 3 = 3 Then: (do nothing) 'an empty statement
   Debug.Print 3 ' <-- This will be executed regardless of the previous If condition
```

To see it, change `3` into this:

```
If 3 = 0 Then:
    Debug.Print 3 '<-- 3 will be printed! ;)
```

In conclusion, yes, the `:` is indeed to merge many statements on a single line

Good job @Vityata !!! :)

Comment: Yep, in that case, you''ll need an endif

Answer (score 3):

If Then Blocks require a matching End If when they are multi-line.

The first case is fine because the command after Then is on the same line.

The second case is fine for the same reason, the : makes no difference in this situation.

The third case works because when the IF statement evaluates to True, there is no command following the ':'.  The : signals to compiler that the next command should be seen as being on the same line.  There is nothing following, so processing moves to the next line which is seen as outside the If Then Block.

The fourth case has no notation to tell the compiler that the If Then command is single line, and therefore it is looking for the End IF to the block.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

  If 1 = 1 Then: Debug.Print 1 '<-- All on a single line - OK

  If 2 = 2 Then Debug.Print 2  '<-- All on a single line - OK

  If 3 = 3 Then:               '<-- No command following :
    Debug.Print 3              '<-- Seen as outside the If Then Block

'   Gives error:
'    If 4 = 4 Then
'        Debug.Print 4
'    End IF                   '<-- Required to show the end of the If Then block
End Sub
```

Comment: `The first one is fine because the command after Then is on the same line.` - but we have a statement deliminator, it should be treated as if it goes on another line.

Comment: @Vityata - No, with the `:` and then the command it is still a single line `If`, just like `If 5 = 5 Then Debug.Print 5: Debug.Print 5: Debug.Print 5`

Comment: @YowE3K - I would have expected an error in case 1 and 3.

Comment: Case 3 works because when the `If` is evaluated to `True` there are no statements to execute (other than the dummy statements preceding / following the `:`).

Comment: @YowE3K Really?  That's kinda cool actually.  I'll update to reflect that.

Comment: @Vityata - I'd suggest you use an example of `If 5 = 5 Then Debug.Print 5::: Debug.Print 5` except that it would make it too obvious what the answer is - that a `:` just separates statements even if one of those statements is a dummy non-statement.  P.S. If you single-step through your code it becomes more apparent what is happening.

Comment: Agree with @YowE3K, I tried it as well, all statements following the `If` and separated with `:` will be merged in one. Following it step by step with the debugger is just amazing!

Comment: @YowE3K, yup, just added it. Looks interesting, did not know it.

Comment: @Vityata - or of course the example `If 5 = 6 Then Debug.Print 5::: Debug.Print 5 Else Debug.Print 6: Debug.Print 6`

Comment: @YowE3K - it is added.