# Case Statement true and False?

Tags: vba, excel, autocad

I'm working on an AutoCAD VBA program that creates a drawing.
But i have a slight problem. If "Case 1" is True Then "Case 2" must be false. Here is my code :

```
Sub Pumps()

'Option for type of pump piping
 ans = InputBox("1 = STD Piping" & vbCrLf & _
                "2 = Omit Pump", "Pump Piping")

Select Case ans

Case "1":

: Set layerObj = ThisDrawing.Layers.Add("PUMP-PIPING STD -" & Size)
            layerObj.LayerOn = True
Case "2":

: Set layerObj = ThisDrawing.Layers.Add("OMIT PUMP -" & Size)
            layerObj.LayerOn = True

Case Else: MsgBox "Wrong Input Dude.", vbCritical, MSG: Exit Sub

End Select

End Sub
```

Please Assist

Comment: what is your actual problem?

Comment: @Jeremy If Case1 is true, I want Case 2 to be false and if Case 2 is True , I want Case1 to be false

Comment: *"i have a slight problem. If "Case 1" is True Then "Case 2" must be false."* - Yes, that is true. I don't see why that's a problem. The user can only input "1" or "2", not both at the same time. Your code works, as far as I can tell.

Comment: well, what you said is true. Is your code not executing as expected?

Comment: If you enter `1`, then your code will **only** add the `PUMP-PIPING STD` object. If you enter `2`, **only** the `OMIT PUMP` object. You're using `Select Case` properly. What makes you think that this is not the case?

Comment: If you found one of the answers to be helpful or answered your question, please mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm not sure what the end goal was, but hopefully this gets you started.

What I've done I've isolated the "decision making" to the `switch` block, and that sets the `toggle` variable which is needed for the "work" to be done later. (and I would consider moving that "work" of actually setting the `layerObj` out to another `Sub`

```
Sub Pumps()
    Dim ans As String

    'Option for type of pump piping
     ans = InputBox("1 = STD Piping" & vbCrLf & _
                    "2 = Omit Pump", "Pump Piping")
    Dim toggle As Boolean

    Select Case ans
        Case "1": toggle = True
        Case "2": toggle = False
        Case Else: MsgBox "Wrong Input Dude.", vbCritical, MSG: Exit Sub
    End Select

    Set layerObj = ThisDrawing.Layers.Add("PUMP-PIPING STD -" & Size)
        layerObj.LayerOn = toggle

    Set layerObj = ThisDrawing.Layers.Add("OMIT PUMP -" & Size)
        layerObj.LayerOn = Not (toggle)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `:` from your code all over. Every single one of them.

It makes plenty of problems, especially with `Conditions`. You really cannot follow what is happening.

In general, the `:` means that you want the next line to stay on the similar line. It is useful only when you want to assign values to a newly declared variable like this: `Dim k as long: k = 5` and its idea is to save space.

Take a look at this topic, you would understand what I mean:
[VBA - How the colon `:` works in VBA code with condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41983020/vba-how-the-colon-works-in-vba-code-with-condition)