# End If/Next C Statement with For Loop / VBA

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I have a fairly complex for `For` Loop with an `If` Statement inside and another `For` Loop inside that. And given a certain criteria (Namely `If InStr(1, q.Value, "Total")`) inside that second For Loops I would like to just end the entire `If` Statement and move to the `Next C`.

I understand that this is layered like an onion and there might not be an easy way out.

```
For Each C In copyRng

        If IsNumeric(C) And C.Value <> "0" And Len(C) <> 0 And C.Value <> "2017" Then 

            Set rowRange = xSheet.Range(C, C.EntireColumn.Cells(1)) 'set range from cell up to the top cell of the comment/ Fix the 2017 thing

            For Each q In rowRange 'Loop through that range and find the Account number just above it and set it as rowSrc
                If InStr(1, q.Value, "C-") And Not ISIN(C, uniqueVal) Then Set rowSrc = q
                If InStr(1, q.Value, "Total") Then End If 'At this point I want to leave the entire If Statement and move on to the next C
            Next q


            Set colSrc = C.EntireRow.Offset(0).Cells(1) 'find alert connected with the number
            numCol = DestSh.Cells.Find(colSrc.Value, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column 'look for the column in which the same alert is listed
            numRow = DestSh.Cells.Find(rowSrc.Value, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row 'look for row in which the same account is listed

            'Set destination
            Set destRng = DestSh.Cells(numRow, numCol)

            'Copy to destination Range
            C.Copy destRng

        End If

    Next C
```

Comment: `If` statements dont work like that. Your line `If..Then End If` is really just saying `If...Then : Do Nothing : End If` since `End If` is just the final line on an `If` block. Likewise, your lines `If...Then _` are problematic since those are line continuation tokens. Don't use them like that. It makes your code difficult to read and to debug. The only way to continue to the next C would be to wrap the code you dont want to run in the reverse of the if `If Not Instr() Then` and then, since the condition wont satisfy, the next C will run.

Comment: @BrandonBarney thanks for the help. I really wasn't sure how the If statements worked and it makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `Exit For` and then after the loop, put the remaining code in yet another `If` block:

```
For Each C In copyRng
    If IsNumeric(C) And C.Value <> "0" And Len(C) <> 0 And C.Value <> "2017" Then
        Set rowRange = xSheet.Range(C, C.EntireColumn.Cells(1))

        For Each q In rowRange
            If InStr(1, q.Value, "C-") And Not ISIN(C, uniqueVal) Then Set rowSrc = q
            If InStr(1, q.Value, "Total") Then Exit For ' Exit loop prematurely
        Next q
        If q is Nothing Then ' Skip if loop was exited prematurely
            Set colSrc = C.EntireRow.Offset(0).Cells(1)
            numCol = DestSh.Cells.Find(colSrc.Value, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
            numRow = DestSh.Cells.Find(rowSrc.Value, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

            Set destRng = DestSh.Cells(numRow, numCol)
            C.Copy destRng
        End If
    End If
Next C
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am realizing that If statements work different from what I imagined. I decided to try out your code and I received the error message "Object variable or With-Variable not identified". Is there a quick fix to that or could that be a larger issue the rest of my code. Should the 'Next q' line maybe be moved down?

Comment: Where did you define `q` and on which line are you geting the error? NB: No, the `Next q` should not be moved down.

Comment: I am getting the error on this line 'If InStr(1, q.Value, "Total") = 0 Then ' Skip if loop was exited prematurely' and I defined the q at the beginning of the code As Range.

Comment: Ok,  could you replace it with `If q Is Nothing Then`?

Comment: I think this would be counter productive, since I want the code to Set destRng and copy C into it if 'InStr(1, q.Value, "C-") And Not ISIN(C, uniqueVal) ' and not if q is nothing. Does that make sense?

Comment: Well, the error you got indicated that `q` was `Nothing`, which is what happens when the loop completes normally. The `If` makes sure that you only execute the rest of the code if indeed the loop was completed normally (without `Exit For`).

Comment: Interesting! I will give this a try immediately

Comment: It did run! Unfortunately my problems aren't all solved since there are a lot of inconsistencies arising, but at least I made a step forward. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Remove each underscore after `Then` and rewrite the whole code. The logic is changed. Pretty much you do not go to the else the way you think it.

Check this:
[VBA - How the colon `:` works in VBA code with condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41983020/vba-how-the-colon-works-in-vba-code-with-condition)

In general, your code does not work the way you think it works. Check the following:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    If 1 = 2 Then _
        Debug.Print "I am true - 1=2"
        Debug.Print "I should be also true"

    If 2 = 3 Then _
        Debug.Print "I am true 2=3"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I need to stop making such liberal use of 'Then _' to ensure cleaner code.

Comment: @FSchildorfer - as a 2. step try putting `Option Explicit` on the top of your code. Something like `If InStr(1, q.Value, "Total") Then End If ` should not be allowed to compile.

Comment: I definitely will.