# Condition inside loop (VBA)

Tags: vba

I wrote this simple sub procedure for Excel VBA. I intentionally used a colon (:) to separate statements. Why doesn't it work?

```
Sub ConditionInsideLoop()

    cb = 0: cd = 1: For ca = 1 To 5: If cd = 1 Then cb = cb + 1: Next

End Sub
```

The question is mostly theoretical. But it might be practical. For example, when we are using the Immediate window and there is a need to use a simple condition inside a simple loop.

Comment: what doesn't work? And where are your variable declarations? Use Option Explicit as well. After formatting properly (for legibility) and adding in declarations works fine for me.

Comment: If you put this line of code into the Immediate Window in VBA it won't work. And it won't work if you run it as a sub procedure. I didn't declare variable explicitly, but I don't think it is the reason why this line of code causes a compile error. Again, we cannot declare variables explicitly in Immediate window. According to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/invalid-in-immediate-window this code should work, but it doesn't

Comment: You are getting a Next without For due to the use of :

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41983139/6241235

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a syntax thing. You can re-write to remove the confounding If statement.

```
Public Sub ConditionInsideLoop()
    Dim cb As Long, cd As Long, ca As Long
    cb = 0: cd = 1: For ca = 1 To 5: cb = IIf(cd = 1, cb + 1, cb): Next
    Debug.Print cb
End Sub
```

Comment: QHarr, IIf function is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why does it hurt to read? I am new in VBA, but learned some other languages, and I am very glad there is something similar to a ternary operator (a?b:c) in VBA

Comment: The use of : in this instance makes the whole thing hard to read. Using indented multi-line makes the logic and control flow much easier to read. It is also easier to debug on multi-lines. IMO there are few times that using : to combine lines is to be favoured over the enhanced legibility of multi-line equivalents.