# Using IsNumeric in a function

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, isnumeric

I wrote a function that generates a "score" (1,0,-1) based on a input cell, which should contain a number. However, sometimes the input field might not be numeric and then the function should return the output "0".

```
Function ScoreRoE(RoE_Field As Range, goodval As Range, badval As Range)

    Dim RoE As Double, result As Double

    RoE = RoE_Field.Value

        If IsNumeric(RoE_Field.Value) = False Then
            result = "0"
        Else:
            If RoE >= goodval.Value Then
                result = "1"
            ElseIf RoE <= badval.Value Then
                result = "-1"
            Else:
                result = "0"
            End If
        End If

    ScoreRoE = result

End Function
```

When the input cell is numeric the function works correctly. However, when not it doesn't and just returns an error "#VALUE!"

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: do your isnumeric test before you assign ROE its initial value.  Otherwise you could be assigning a string to a double and things do not look promising there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare RoE as Variant:

```
Function ScoreRoE(RoE_Field As Range, goodval As Range, badval As Range)

    Dim RoE As Variant, result As Double

    RoE = RoE_Field.Value

        If Not IsNumeric(RoE) Then
            result = 0
        Else
            If RoE >= goodval.Value Then
                result = 1
            ElseIf RoE <= badval.Value Then
                result = -1
            Else
                result = 0
            End If
        End If

    ScoreRoE = result

End Function
```

you cannot assign a text value to a double.

---

Personally I do not see the need for any of the variables:

```
Function ScoreRoE(RoE_Field As Range, goodval As Range, badval As Range)

    If Not IsNumeric(RoE_Field.Value) Then
        ScoreRoE = 0
    Else
        If RoE_Field.Value >= goodval.Value Then
            ScoreRoE = 1
        ElseIf RoE_Field.Value <= badval.Value Then
            ScoreRoE = -1
        Else
            ScoreRoE = 0
        End If
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: @ForwardEd  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Is there particular reason for using RoE instead of dealing with RoE_Field.Value directly aside from keystrokes?

Comment: @ForwardEd I personally do not see the need to use any of the variables but wanted to keep as closely as possible to what the OP is using.

Comment: not that it is REQUIRED, but shouldn't the function be assigned a variable type instead of letting it default to variant?

Comment: @ForwardEd I usually leave it as variant when outputting to a sheet, but that is personal preference.

Comment: @ForwardEd arguably if `RoE_Field.Value` (or any of the inputs) is an `Error` value, the function should return `CVErr(xlErrValue)` as a `Variant/Error`, not `0`. That can't be cleanly done without returning a `Variant`.

Comment: No, all those variables are not required. That was a great help, much leaner code this way

Comment: @yannk  IF you want leaner, define `ScoreROE=0` at the get go.  follow by a check to see if `RoE_Field.Value` IS a number.  And then if it is do your two checks for good value then bad value.  Everything else will be zero as that was what you initialized at the start.

Answer (score 2):

This is an interpretation of the intentions of the code:

```
Function ScoreRoe(roeInput As String, goodVal As String, badVal As String) As String

    If Not IsNumeric(roeInput) Or Not IsNumeric(goodVal) Or Not IsNumeric(badVal) Then
        ScoreRoe = "0"
    Else
        Dim goodValNumeric As Double: goodValNumeric = goodVal
        Dim badValNumeric As Double: badValNumeric = badVal
        Dim roeInputNumeric As Double: roeInputNumeric = roeInput

        If roeInputNumeric >= goodValNumeric Then
            ScoreRoe = "1"
        ElseIf roeInputNumeric <= badValNumeric Then
            ScoreRoe = "-1"
        Else
            ScoreRoe = "0"
        End If
    End If

End Function
```

The main idea is that the input is taken as `String` and then converted to `Double` for the comparison. Then if the input is not numeric, the returned value is `0` and if it is we go through If-Else.

In general, it could be a good idea to avoid `:` in VBA `If-Else`, in order to avoid unwanted problems like this one - [VBA - How the colon `:` works in VBA code with condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41983020/vba-how-the-colon-works-in-vba-code-with-condition)

Comment: Interesting take on the situation.  Not the route I would naturally thought of, but nice way of coming at the issue from a different angle.

Comment: @ForwardEd - well, I started by removing the `_` from the variables' names, then removed the `:`, then decided to do it completely different way :)